# If $α,β,γ,δ$ be the roots of the equation $x^4 + px^3 + qx^2 + rx + s = 0$, then find in terms of $p,q,r,s$ the value of $\sum α^4$

Tags: polynomials

If $α,β,γ,δ$ be the roots of the equation $x^4 + px^3 + qx^2 + rx + s = 0$ ,then find in terms of $p,q,r,s$ the value of $\sum \alpha^4$

My general strategy was transforming the equation to one whose roots are $\alpha^4,etc$ but it seems to be impossible as the transformed equation with $y=\alpha^4(\implies y^{1/4}=\alpha)$ is $y+py^{3/4}+qy^{1/2}+ry^{1/4}+s=0,$ which *is not even a polynomial in $y$* and hence we can't apply Vieta's formulas.

Next, I tried simplifying the expression $\sum \alpha^4$ but, it doesn't turn out favourable as a huge calculation appears which couldn't be simplified more and no desirable form was obtained and this was in vain too. I don't understand how to approach it...

Comment: You can find the answer here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities ($p_4$ is given in terms of $e_i$s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT…use $$\Sigma\alpha^4=-p\Sigma\alpha^3-q\Sigma\alpha^2-r\Sigma\alpha-s\Sigma 1$$
And $$\Sigma\alpha^3=-p\Sigma\alpha^2-q\Sigma\alpha-r\Sigma 1-s\Sigma\frac{1}{\alpha}$$
And all the remaining terms can easily be obtained using Vieta etc.

Comment: Is $\Sigma\alpha^4=-p\Sigma\alpha^3-q\Sigma\alpha^2-r\Sigma\alpha-s\Sigma1$ a popular result?

Comment: @Franklin not really a result as much as it is a simple manipulaino: Just note that every root satisfies the given equation and make the fourth power the subject. Write four such equations and add.

Comment: @insipidintegrator Ohh! I see it now. But then again, how do you calculate the $\Sigma\alpha^2$ ? Should we do tge normal bashing and at some point get our required result, but that's still becomes a long way, as we then have to expand $(\alpha+\beta+\gamma+\delta)^2$, which is huge! What do you suggest?

Comment: Use $\Sigma\alpha^2=\left(\Sigma\alpha\right)^2-2\Sigma\alpha\beta$

Comment: And yes I would say what I wrote in my hint is a fairly standard method…

Comment: @DavidQuinn Thanks! I do get it now...

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: I have stressed the "fairly standard method" aspect in the answer I just wrote.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$x^4+qx^2+s=-x(px^2+r)\implies(x^4+qx^2+s)^2=(-x)^2(px^2+r)^2$$

Replacing $x^2$ with $y$

$$(y^2+qy+s)^2=y(py+r)^2\iff y^4+(2q-p^2)y^3+y^2(q^2+2s-2pr)+y(2qs-r^2)+s^2=0$$ whose roots are $\alpha^2,\beta^2,\gamma^2,\delta^2$

$$\implies\alpha^4+\beta^4+\gamma^4+\delta^4=(p^2-2q)^2-2(q^2+2s-2pr)=?$$

Comment: Your result $(p^2-2q)^2-2(q^2+2s-2pr)$ is the correct one but there are lacking steps. IMHO you should have said, prior to the last line : "as we have succeeded to go from the sum of the roots to the sum of their squares (letter $y$), let us do the same thing to get the sum of the fourth power of the roots (letter $z$); let us write for that the last equ. $y^4+Py^3+Qy^2+Ry+S=0$, with, in particular, $P=2q-p^2$ from which we deduce $z^4+Pz^3+Qz^2+Rz+S=0$ where the coefficient of $z^3$ (the one which "holds" the opposite of the sum of the roots),  is $P'=2Q-P^2$ (the opposite of your formula).

Answer (score 0):

[From Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), we have:

$$p = - (\alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta) \tag{1}$$
$$q = (\alpha\beta + \alpha\gamma + \alpha\delta + \beta\gamma + \beta\delta + \gamma\delta) \tag{2}$$
$$r = - (\alpha\beta\gamma + \alpha\beta\delta + \alpha\gamma\delta + \beta\gamma\delta) \tag{3}$$
$$s = \alpha\beta\gamma\delta \tag{4}$$

Squaring equation (1) gives:

$$p^2 = (\alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta)^2$$
$$p^2 = \alpha^2 + \beta^2 + \gamma^2 + \delta^2 + 2(\alpha\beta + \alpha\gamma + \alpha\delta + \beta\gamma + \beta\delta + \gamma\delta)$$

But using equation (2), this can be simplified to:

$$p^2 - 2q = \alpha^2 + \beta^2 + \gamma^2 + \delta^2 \tag{5}$$

Now let's try *cubing* equation 1.

$$-p^3 = (\alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta)^3$$
$$-p^3 = \alpha^3 + \beta^3 + \gamma^3 + \delta^3 + 3\alpha^2(\beta + \gamma + \delta) + 3\beta^2(\alpha + \gamma + \delta) + 3\gamma^2(\alpha + \beta + \gamma) + 3\delta^2(\alpha + \beta + \gamma) + 6(\alpha\beta\gamma + \alpha\beta\delta + \alpha\gamma\delta + \beta\gamma\delta)$$
$$-p^3 = \alpha^3 + \beta^3 + \gamma^3 + \delta^3 + 3\alpha^2(-p - \alpha) + 3\beta^2(-p - \beta) + 3\gamma^2(-p - \gamma) + 3\delta^2(-p - \delta) - 6r$$
$$-p^3 = -2(\alpha^3 + \beta^3 + \gamma^3 + \delta^3) - 3p(\alpha^2 + \beta^2 + \gamma^2 + \delta^2) - 6r$$
$$-p^3 = -2(\alpha^3 + \beta^3 + \gamma^3 + \delta^3) - 3p(p^2-2q) - 6r$$
$$-p^3 + 3pq - 3r = \alpha^3 + \beta^3 + \gamma^3 + \delta^3 \tag{6}$$

Finally, raise equation (1) to the fourth power.

$$p^4 = (\alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta)^4$$
$$p^4 = \alpha^4 + \beta^4 + \gamma^4 + \delta^4 + 4\alpha^3(\beta + \gamma + \delta) + 4\beta^3(\alpha + \gamma + \delta) + 4\gamma^3(\alpha + \beta + \delta) + 4\delta^3(\alpha + \beta + \gamma) + 6(\alpha^2\beta^2 + \alpha^2\gamma^2 + \alpha^2\delta^2 + \beta^2\gamma^2 + \beta^2\delta^2 + \gamma^2\delta^2) + 12\alpha^2(\beta\gamma + \beta\delta + \gamma\delta) + 12\beta^2(\alpha\gamma + \alpha\delta + \gamma\delta) + 12\gamma^2(\alpha\beta + \alpha\delta + \beta\delta) + 12\delta^2(\alpha\beta + \alpha\gamma + \beta\gamma) + 24\alpha\beta\gamma\delta$$
$$p^4 = \alpha^4 + \beta^4 + \gamma^4 + \delta^4 + 4\alpha^3(-p - \alpha) + 4\beta^3(-p - \beta) + 4\gamma^3(-p - \gamma) + 4\delta^3(-p - \delta) + 3(\alpha^2(p^2 - 2q - \alpha^2) + \beta^2(p^2 - 2q - \beta^2) + \gamma^2(p^2 - 2q - \gamma^2) + \delta^2(p^2 - 2q - \delta^2)) + 12\alpha^2(-r - \alpha(-p-\alpha)) + 12\beta^2(-r - \beta(-p - \beta)) + 12\gamma^2(-r - \gamma(-p - \gamma)) + 12\delta^2(-r-\delta(-p - \delta)) + 24s$$
$$p^4 = \alpha^4 + \beta^4 + \gamma^4 + \delta^4 - 4\alpha^3p - 4\alpha^4 - 4\beta^3p - 4\beta^4 - 4\gamma^3p - 4\gamma^4 - 4\delta^3p - 4\delta^4 + 3\alpha^2p^2 - 6\alpha^2q - 3\alpha^4 + 3\beta^2p^2 - 6\beta^2q - 3\beta^4 + 3\gamma^2p^2 - 6\gamma^2q - 3\gamma^4 + 3\delta^2p^2 - 6\delta^2q - 3\delta^4 - 12\alpha^2r + 12\alpha^3 p + 12\alpha^4 - 12\beta^2r + 12\beta^3 p + 12\beta^4 - 12\gamma^2r + 12\gamma^3 p + 12\gamma^4 - 12\delta^2r + 12\delta^3 p + 12\delta^4 + 24s$$
$$p^4 = 6(\alpha^4 + \beta^4 + \gamma^4 + \delta^4) + 8p(\alpha^3 + \beta^3 + \gamma^3 + \delta^3) + (3p^2 - 6q - 12r)(\alpha^2 + \beta^2 + \gamma^2 + \delta^2) + 24s$$
$$p^4 = 6(\alpha^4 + \beta^4 + \gamma^4 + \delta^4) + 8p(-p^3 + 3pq - 3r) + (3p^2 - 6q - 12r)(p^2 - 2q) + 24s$$
$$p^4 = 6(\alpha^4 + \beta^4 + \gamma^4 + \delta^4) - 8p^4 + 24p^2q - 24pr + 3p^4 - 6p^2q - 6p^2q + 12q^2 - 12p^2r + 24qr + 24s$$
$$\boxed{\alpha^4 + \beta^4 + \gamma^4 + \delta^4 = p^4 - 2p^2q + 2p^2r - 2q^2 + 4pr - 4qr - 4s}$$

Comment: Sorry, but your result is not exact. It is not far from the correct one found by Lab Bhattacharjee (I have checked both formulas on different random monic 4th degree polynomials).

Answer (score 0):

There is a *direct* formula (see (1) below) issued from **Newton identities** that can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities).

In order to understand it, we must give the notations used in this article.

- Coefficients $e_k$ are equal to $(-1)^k$ times the coefficients of the initial polynomial, namely :

$$p(x)=x^4-e_1x^3+e_2x^2-e_3x+e_4$$

- Notation $p_k$ is for the sum of the $k$-th powers of the roots. Then :

$$p_{4}=e_{1}p_{3}-e_{2}p_{2}+e_{3}p_{1}-4e_{4}=e_{1}^{4}-4e_{1}^{2}e_{2}+4e_{1}e_{3}+2e_{2}^{2}-4e_{4}\tag{1}$$

giving the final result :

$$p_4=p^4-4p^2q+4pr+2q^2-4s$$

in coincidence with the result of @Lab Bhattacharjee.